# How to use server side validation in php on this demo form?

Tags: validation, server

```
<!--------- THIS IS A DEMO FORM I WANT TO VALIDATE THIS ON SERVER SIDE -->


 <form name= "registration" id= "registration" method= "post" action= "">
 <table width= "400" border= "0" align="center" cellpadding= "4" cellspacing= "1">
    <tr>
    <td>Employee Name:</td>
    <td><input name= "emp_name" type= "text" id="emp_name" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Contact No.: </td>
    <td><input name= "emp_number" type= "text" id= "emp_number" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Personal Email: </td>
    <td><input name= "emp_email" type= "text" id= "emp_email" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td><input type= "submit" name= "Submit" value= "Submit" ></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: First you have to send it to the server somehow. How are you doing that? Then you can validate it with a bunch of if/then statements in PHP. That's the easy part. Then you have to send the result back to the web page and make it show whether it was valid or not. Do you know what you're using to do that? What I just said is going to take you a lot more time than the validation part.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to make sure the form redirects the script to a PHP file or this HTML is inside the PHP file.

It is not clear what you mean by validation but if you would like to validate for empty fields, you can try this:

```
if($_POST["emp_name"] == "") { // Used post because that is what you specified in your form tag
    echo 'Please fill out the employee name'; // Output stuff here
}
```